# Is there any way to use "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()" in unity3d 2021.3.5 LTS?

Tags: unity-game-engine, oledbconnection

Is there any way to use "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()" in unity3d 2021.3.5 LTS?

1. I got **System.Data.OleDb.dll**(v6.0) from Nuget
   (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.OleDb/)
2. CopyPaste this dll file into Unity's **Assets/Plugins** Folder
3. Set **Project Settings>Api Compatibillity Level** is *.NET Standard 2.1*

**No compile error** in *Visual Studio* **but i met this error** when play project:

> ERROR : PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Data.OleDb is not supported on this platform.
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection..ctor (System.String connectionString) (at <80f9cbd305374b2c81b86ae9cc413864>:0)
> (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection..ctor(string)

DLL : /lib/netstandard2.0/System.Data.OleDb.dll from NuGet.zip(nupkg) file

Unity's Build Target Platform : Windows 64x

Comment: `I got "System.Data.OleDb.dll(v6.0)" from Nuget` for what platform is his DLL compiled? and what is your target platform?

Answer (score 0):

OP:

*"Copy [NuGet] dll into Assets/Plugins Folder"*

That's not how to use NuGet and that's not how to use the **Plugins** folder.

> ERROR : PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Data.OleDb is not supported on this platform.
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection..ctor (System.String connectionString) (at <80f9cbd305374b2c81b86ae9cc413864>:0)
> (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection..ctor(string)

This is caused by using the wrong "bitness" version of a DLL on Windows.  i.e. mixing up x86 with x64.  In *Visual Studio* right-click your solution and select **Manage NuGet Packages**, search for and add the NuGet package that way.  Visual Studio will ensure that the **correct bitness** version of the DLL is downloaded.

What happens next depends on why you are using the **Plugins** folder.

a) **Unity project code:** your Visual Studio solution was created by Unity and all your code resides beneath the **Assets** folder.  Your code makes references to the Unity API and so requires Unity to be present.  In this scenario you have no need for the **Plugins** folder because anything you create is immediately visible (unless you made ASMDEFs, a topic for another day)

b) **External, pre-compiled "plugin" for Unity:**  Your Visual Studio solution along with all code was created external to and independent to Unity.  You can work on your code even if Unity isn't installed.  Your code is compiled to a DLL and later deployed by whatever means to Unity's **Plugins** folder.

> Project Settings>Api Compatibillity Level is .NET Standard 2.1

Remember, *external to Unity or not,* the latest compatible **.NET Standard** that Unity will recognise is [.NET Standard 2.1](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/dotnetProfileSupport.html) (which is equivalent to a **.NET Core 3.0** class library).  Meanwhile you can use **.NET Framework 4.x**.

### What's in a plugin?

The term "plugin" is a bit misleading since there is no requirement that the DLL has to expose anything in particular to be considered a plugin.  Managed DLLs can be added to Unity even though there is no "Unity" anything in the DLL. e.g. a re-usable C# *Systems of Measurement* library DLL.

Comment: @므.. no worries.  Don't forget to _accept_ answer by clicking the Tick button above and optionally up-voting.   It helps feed the kids. :)